# All log ins are directed to one account. Log in script issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I made a log in script but even I log in different accounts it directs me to same account all over again. Aside from lesser password security (which is not my concern for this moment), please help me correct this script.

Student_login.php

```
<body onLoad="javascript:document.form1.learner_id.focus()">

<?php include 'Header.php';?>

<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li class='active'><a href='index.php'><span>PNHS Home</span></a></li>
        <li class='last'><span></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<?php if(!empty($_GET['flag']) && $_GET['flag'] == "success"){?>
<div align="center" class="stylered">
    Congratulations! You are successfully registered. You can use your Learner Id and Password to login  your account.
</div>
<?php } ?>
<br>
<br>
<form name="form2" method="post" action="Student_login_handler.php" onSubmit="return validate();">  
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><table width="30%"  border="1" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#666666" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <tr align="center" bgcolor="#999999">
                <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CC33" class="styleblock">Learner Login Here</td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1" class="stylesmall">
                <td width="35%" align="left" class="stylesmall">Learner Id : </td>
                <td width="65%" align="left"><input name="learner_id" type="text" id="learner_id"  method="post"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1" class="stylesmall">
                <td align="left" class="stylesmall">Password:</td>
                <td align="left"><input name="student_password" type="password" id="student_password" method="post"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1">  
                <td colspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;
                    <?php if(!empty($_GET['flag']) && $_GET['flag'] == "invalid") { ?>
                    <span class="stylered">Invalid Learner Id or Password</span>
                    <?php }?>
                </td>
```

Student_login_handler.php

```
$learner_id = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['learner_id']));
$student_password =  mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['student_password']));
$student_id = htmlentities($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES);
$student_id = htmlentities($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES);
$query = "SELECT student_id,last_login_date FROM student_information WHERE learner_id='$learner_id' and student_password='$student_password'";
$result = mysqli_query($link_id, $query);

if(mysqli_error() != null){
    die(mysqli_error());
}
if($date = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     $lastdate = $date['last_login_date'];
     $date2 = date("d-m-Y h:i A",strtotime($lastdate));
     $_SESSION['user_id'] = $date['student_id'];
     $_SESSION["lastlogin"] =$date2;
     $_SESSION["type"] = "Student";
    mysqli_query("UPDATE student_information SET last_login_date=now() where student_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}'",$link_id);
     if(mysqli_error() != null){
        die(mysqli_error());
    }
     header("location:  Student_Home.php?id={$_SESSION}");
     die();
}
else
{
    $flag = "invalid";
    header("location:Student_login.php?flag=$flag");
    die();
```

Please suggest me guys what to do.

Comment: What are you passing in the query string?

Comment: change `Student_Home.php?id={$_SESSION}` to `Student_Home.php?id={$_SESSION['user_id']}`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what this is meant to do:

```
header("location:  Student_Home.php?id={$_SESSION}");
```

`$_SESSION` is a collection of values, so what would that even output?  Do you mean to redirect to the user's ID?:

```
header("location:  Student_Home.php?id={$_SESSION['user_id']}");
```

---

Note that there are a number of other things wrong here:

1. The form uses POST, but it looks like you're fetching values from `$_GET` as well?  But then you don't seem to do anything with that value.  Though the fact that it's there at all leads me to suspect that somewhere in this application you're trusting user input, such as letting a user *specify* their ID.  You'll want to make sure you don't do that.
2. You're storing user passwords in plain text.  ***Never ever do that.***
3. You may be escaping user input, but I suspect you're not effectively eliminating SQL injection here.  Even if you coincidentally are in this one case, this style of coding suggests that there will be vulnerabilities in your application.  You'll want to make it a habit to use prepared statements instead of using variables directly in your SQL queries.  You won't always have complete end-to-end control over those variables.

Comment: @Aakanksha i tried your suggestion but it affects nothing. Please.

Comment: Yeah i wanted it to redirect it to a specific user id but it doesnt. It just log in to same account/same user ID even i am using diffrent accounts to log in

Comment: @NoviceSiteUploader: Did you try my suggestion?  What was the resulting change in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
header("location:  Student_Home.php?id={$_SESSION}");
```

to this

```
header("location:  Student_Home.php?id={$_SESSION['user_id']}");
```

Or better simply use

```
header("location:  Student_Home.php");
```

and you can take out the value at Student_Home.php by:

```
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Comment: TO RAJANKUR: appreciate your effort,it really did work. But one more thing why is that even if i won't fill up the learner id and password field. I still directed to one account? PLEASE adVISE.

Comment: Well you will have a use some kind of checks for that, You can check on Student_Home.php whether the **user_id** is in SESSION or not, if not redirect them back to the login page.